# Why does my macOS always shutdown automatically after I left it?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

My mac mini is macOS mojave, and my battery settings is as follows:

[image]
[image]

But every time I left the computer for a while, it shutdowns automatically, what is the problem and how can I prevent it shutdown?

Comment: Click the “Schedule…” button and see if you have scheduled a shutdown time.

Comment: No shutdown time schedule...

Comment: Sounds like some sort of power or overheating issue. Check the Console for any logs stating why it shut down. Finder > Applications > Utilities > Console. The logs may be able to direct you/us better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root cause occasionally!

Uncheck the "Log out after xxx minutes of inactivity" should fix the problem!!!

The setting is in "Security & Privacy" --> "Advanced".

[image]